# React Router - Getting a page not found when not explicitly arriving at a dynamic route URL via a link or history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, react-router, url-routing

I'm trying to troubleshoot why I'm getting a "Page Not Found" / 404 page(?) in my application.

I have a router set up as follows:

```
<Router>
  <Search/>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/cafes" component={ListView} />
    <Route
      path="/cafes/results/:loc"
      component={Results}
     />
     <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

If I use the `<Search>` component, it will call the results route via this code:

```
this.props.history.push({
      pathname: `/cafes/results/${searchAddress}`,
    });
```

and that `<Results>` page component will successfully display search results. It will have a URL like: `http://myurl.com/cafes/results/Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA%2C%20USA`.

However, if I refresh the page, I get a page not found.

The `<NotFound>` component, from my understanding, should catch any routes that don't match the ones above it, but that's not happening.

It is a react app running within a Wordpress setup for which any URL starting with `cafes` should be suppressed from Wordpress's setup (though I don't know much about that bit, I didn't set it up). Is it possible that the issue is related to Wordpress, or have I messed something up within my react-router setup?

Comment: Is the notfound page you get from Wordpress or from the front web server (Apache or nginx)?

Comment: It looks to be from Wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a client-side (React or whatever) issue. A proof of this is the fact that all works while you stay on client (so: calling `.push` API) but as soon as you reload you go the the server.

You must configure your front web server to always publish your page for every location under `/cafes`.

This is commonly done by using an Apache/NGINX configuration.

An NGINX example could be:

```
location / {
  root /path/to/your/build/directory
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

I'm not sure is Wordpress can do this for you (but I'm not sure that's would be a good idea anyway)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using webpack dev server, then add this to webpack config:

```
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
```

Comment: Why downvote? This answer is correct in case he is using webpack dev server.